# I installed php 7.4.27 but is it okay if I use php 7.3.10's phpini file?

Tags: php

I wanted to update the php version. However, when I use the phpini file in it, it does not see things like mysql. I also took phpini from the old php 7.3.10 file and used it. It worked, I didn't see any problems, but is there a possibility that there is a problem?

Comment: It would be better to make the changes that were made to the old ini, to the new one.  You could also run a diff on both files, to see the changes that you and the distributor made.

Comment: It's best to use the up-to-date file because it might have version-specific config options. I use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to easily compare text files.